# Metodo setSpeakerphoneOn() de Audio Manager genera interferencia.

Tags: android, android-studio, audio-manager

Estoy utilizando Sinch para implementar una llamada de voz "App to App".

Mi problema surge cuando intento activar el altavoz.

Creo una instancia de audio manager en el onCreate() de mi actividad:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Tengo un botón que activa el altavoz, mediante las siguientes instrucciones:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    }
}, 500);
```

Lo anterior sí activa el altavoz, sin embargo, genera una interferencia o ruido muy molesto.

He probado eliminar la linea

audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);`

y aumentar el delay de `500` a  `2000` como lo sugieren algunas respuesta a este problema, pero nada de esto me ha dado resultados.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿qué tipo de interferencia/ruido es el que genera?

Comment: No sabría clasificarlo. Es un bip tone distorsionado que aumenta de volumen